# Dockerfile for node:16-alpine in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have been struggling with creating a dockerFile from node:16-alpine base image for AWS Lambda. Anything I find on the internet is outdated and I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated at this stage.

Here is my current dockerfile:

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/app"

#*****************************************************************************
#  Builder Stage
#****************************************************************************/
FROM node:16-alpine AS base

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# The working directory is where "npm install" created the node_modules folder.
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies. aws-lambda-cpp is used by aws-lambda-ric which is a
# node-gyp compiled dependency. Find it in package.json.
# See the Node.js example at https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-nodejs-runtime-interface-client
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libstdc++ \
    build-base \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    elfutils-dev \
    make \
    cmake \
    libcurl \
    python3

# Copy dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the AWS Lambda Runtime Interface Client (RIC) that is only required within this Docker container (not in package.json on development machine).
# It helps AWS to run the Lambda function code that autoiXpert provides.
RUN npm install
RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric
RUN npm prune --production

RUN npm ci
COPY src/main ./
RUN npm run docker-build

#*****************************************************************************
#  Production Stage
#****************************************************************************/
FROM node:16-alpine

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

# The working directory is where "npm install" created the node_modules folder.
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

COPY --from=base app/dist ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/npx", "aws-lambda-ric"]
CMD [ "app.lambdaHandler" ]
```

When I run "docker build ." This is the error I get on the line of "RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric":

```
#16 424.3 npm ERR!  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcurl-multi.3 libcurl-security.3 libcurl-share.3 libcurl-symbols.3 libcurl-thread.3 libcurl-tutorial.3 libcurl-url.3 libcurl.3 '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/artifacts/share/man/man3'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! make[6]: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/curl-curl-7_83_1/docs/libcurl'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! make[5]: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/curl-curl-7_83_1/docs/libcurl'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! make[4]: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/curl-curl-7_83_1/docs/libcurl'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! make[3]: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/curl-curl-7_83_1'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! make[2]: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/curl-curl-7_83_1'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! make[1]: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/curl-curl-7_83_1'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Detecting CXX compile features
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Found CURL: /app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric/deps/artifacts/lib/libcurl.a (found version "7.83.1-DEV")
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Looking for backtrace
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Looking for backtrace - not found
#16 424.3 npm ERR! -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
#16 424.3 npm ERR! *** Do not use buildconf. Instead, just use: autoreconf -fi
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure.ac:120: installing './compile'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure.ac:317: installing './config.guess'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure.ac:317: installing './config.sub'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure.ac:120: installing './install-sh'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure.ac:125: installing './missing'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! docs/examples/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! parallel-tests: installing './test-driver'
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure: WARNING: zlib disabled
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure: WARNING: Use --with-openssl, --with-gnutls, --with-wolfssl, --with-mbedtls, --with-nss, --with-schannel, --with-secure-transport, --with-amissl, --with-bearssl or --with-rustls to address this.
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure: WARNING: libgsasl was not found
#16 424.3 npm ERR! configure: WARNING: disabling built-in manual
#16 424.3 npm ERR! CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
#16 424.3 npm ERR!   Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)
#16 424.3 npm ERR! Call Stack (most recent call first):
#16 424.3 npm ERR!   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
#16 424.3 npm ERR!   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBacktrace.cmake:90 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
#16 424.3 npm ERR!   CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)
```

Is there anyone out there who can help me with this?

Thanks and regards,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround on github ([reference](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-nodejs-runtime-interface-client/issues/68)).
"libexecinfo-dev" is a must for aws-lambda-ric. It can't be simply replaced by the "elfutils-dev" even though it's suggested in several internet forums.

Here is the workaround to import the libexecinfo-dev. It will allow you to install aws-lambda-ric:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --update --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/ libexecinfo-dev
```